# How to get files dynamically from folder, subfolder and its subfolder in webpack javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I am trying to build a small application in `VueJs` with `webpack`, where I want to includes a `config/routing` files dynamically from folders. I have a folder structure something like this:

```
plugins
|----Ecommerce
|--------backend
|--------frontend
|------------config.js
|------------routes.js
|------------components
|----------------products.vue
|----Blog
|--------backend
|--------frontend
|------------config.js
|------------routes.js
|------------components
|----------------posts.vue
```

For this I am trying to include my files with:

```
const configRequire = require.context('./../plugins/', true, /\.\/[^/]+\/config\.js$/);
const routesRequire = require.context('./../plugins/', true, /\.\/[^/]+\/routes\.js$/);
```

But somehow it is not including the files. I guess something wrong with my regex

**Edit:**

Found out the problem, my files are not getting imported as it is inside `folders/subfolder/subfolder`, if I keep the folder structure as this:

```
plugins
|----Ecommerce
|--------backend
|--------config.js
|--------routes.js
|--------frontend
|------------components
|----------------products.vue
|----Blog
|--------backend
|--------config.js
|--------routes.js
|--------frontend
|------------components
|----------------posts.vue
```

I can see my files getting imported. But doesn't get when I keep my `config/routes` files inside `frontend` folder

Help me out in this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `require.context` syntax, but is the regex containing `route\.js` and the actual file containing `route` *`s`* `.js` a type that that you introduced when copying the question to StackOverflow

Comment: @Ferrybig Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Try adjusting your regex, your are matching for `./` which only works in the current directory (plugins), not in any of its subdirectories. Fix the regex and you should be fine.

Comment: @TommyF yes true, but I don't know much of it.

Comment: Well thanks to all, I did `/\.\/[^/]+\/[frontend]+\/config\.js$/` and it worked out. @TommyF

Comment: that is by accident, this is not what you want @NitishKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this to better understand your current regex: https://regex101.com/r/Y9sDZc/1 (remove the first line to see how it doesn't match the second.)

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you want to match and what not, so I can only guess what the correct solution for your case is, but here are some options:
`config\.js` matches all files called `config.js`. Directories are taken care of by your `require.context` parameters. This would also match `plugins/foo/bar/config.js/somefile.txt` though, if you control all files and are sure this isn't a problem using `config\.js` is your simplest solution.

A bit more selective would be:
`.*\/config\.js$`

Hope that helps.